# Pycharm/IntelliJ IDEA: how to decrease width of code delimiter?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

How to make this vertical bar thinner? It is thinner without line numbers than with them but still to fat for my little screen.

[image: pycharm code delimiter]

Comment: What version are you running?  From what I can tell, IntelliJ does seem to be a lot thinner with the 2016.x builds.

Comment: @Makoto version: 2016.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto File > Settings > Editor> General > Gutter Icons.

uncheck the option `Show gutter icons`.

Now the desired appearance, 
[image]

Comment: You can't set and see the breakpoints if you hide the gutter as these icons are shown on the gutter!

Answer (score 1):

Even better in Distraction Free Mode:
[image: pycharm distraction free mode]