# PyCharm how to adjust gutter width?

Tags: pycharm, gutter

The other day I mis-clicked on and mis-dragged something probably and then the left "side bar" of the editor window got wider than normal.

[image: screenshot of gutter in editor]

Since this happened by mis-clicking and dragging, I don't know how to reset it back to the normal width. It simply doesn't respond when I try to click and drag the borderline. Didn't find anything related in `Settings` either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm/IntelliJ IDEA: how to decrease width of code delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000506/pycharm-intellij-idea-how-to-decrease-width-of-code-delimiter)

Comment: See [IDEA-148002](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002) and also [PY-51385](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-51385)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change the gutter width at the moment. It adjusts itself automatically when needed (e.g. there is a gutter icon for override method and a breakpoint on the same line).
Looking at your screenshot, the width is actually standard. It needs some extra space to allow you setting breakpoints without accidentally clicking the line number.
You could submit a feature request/usability problem to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA, but to me, it seems fine.

But since you say it was different the other day and then something happened and it became wider, you could try starting PyCharm with default settings by renaming/removing configuration folder. Here is the [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) on how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings -> Editor -> General -> Gutter Icon* and uncheck the **Show gutter icons**.

But you should be careful: this action will hide information about recursive calls,  override methods etc...

Comment: Sorry but you seem to misunderstand my question. The problem isn't with the gutter icons (override information etc.). Even without the gutter icon, the "bar" itself is still too wide. I have edited my question.

Comment: Found this topic: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206170719-Gutter-width-line-numbers- not sure that exist way to fix it